# Codeigniter - undefined property $grocery_crud

Tags: php, codeigniter

*Very* new to Codeingiter and trying to implement Grocery CRUD following this tutorial http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/create-crud-codeigniter-tutorial.

Have done so in the following code (by the way, I'm autoloading database library and url helper).

```
<?php

class Management extends CI_Controller {


public function construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
}

public function index ()
{
    echo "<h1>Just work!</h1>";
    die();
}


public function property ()
{
    $this->grocery_crud->set_table('property');
    $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($output);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
}


/**
public function view($page = 'management_page')
{
    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }



    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter



    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);               
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
**/
}
```

However, when I load this page at [BASE ]/management/property I get the following error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Management::$grocery_crud

Filename: controllers/management.php

Line Number: 21
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try having the library load name all lower case.

Comment: No good I'm afraid, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved this now, not 100% sure as I've moved on quite a bit in my code and DB structure, but I think was simply to do with not having the 'property' table in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

Object missing ??

```
$crud = new Grocery_CRUD();
```

and after set the database table

```
$crud->set_table('property');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of users encountering the same issue: Try loading the grocery_crud library with a caps 'G'. In other words change:

```
  $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
```

To:

```
  $this->load->library('Grocery_CRUD');
```